# dplyr: cbind columns based on timestamp

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am stuck with this problem and can't think of any simple `dplyr` to solve it:

I have two data.frames `df1` and `df2`. I want to sort of 'cbind' the values of the `time2` column from `df2` to `df1`, but only if the `user_id` and the `place_id` matches:

```
> head(df1)
                time1 user_id   place_id
1 2018-06-09 12:56:12  sdkID1  place_ID1
2 2018-06-24 05:15:07  sdkID1  place_ID1
3 2018-06-12 04:15:21  sdkID1 place_ID10
4 2018-06-12 14:56:42  sdkID1 place_ID17
5 2018-05-16 18:21:51  sdkID1 place_ID20
6 2018-07-11 12:19:27  sdkID1 place_ID21
> head(df2)
                time2 user_id   place_id
1 2018-06-09 13:12:39  sdkID1  place_ID1
2 2018-06-24 06:52:51  sdkID1  place_ID1
3 2018-06-12 05:50:19  sdkID1 place_ID10
4 2018-05-16 19:42:59  sdkID1 place_ID20
5 2018-07-11 12:23:44  sdkID1 place_ID21
6 2018-06-13 11:56:05  sdkID1 place_ID34
```

However I do not have any `id` variable to check that `time2` from `df2` belongs to `df1`. To spice things up, for some events I do not have any timestamp to match to `df1`.

I want something like:

```
> head(result)
                time1 user_id   place_id               time2 
1 2018-06-09 12:56:12  sdkID1  place_ID1 2018-06-09 13:12:39 
2 2018-06-24 05:15:07  sdkID1  place_ID1 2018-06-24 06:52:51 
3 2018-06-12 04:15:21  sdkID1 place_ID10 2018-06-12 05:50:19 
4 2018-06-12 14:56:42  sdkID1 place_ID17                  NA
5 2018-05-16 18:21:51  sdkID1 place_ID20 2018-05-16 19:42:59 
6 2018-07-11 12:19:27  sdkID1 place_ID21 2018-07-11 12:23:44
```

> Is there some way to take `time2-time1` only keep the rows with
>   positive time difference? I know there is. But then I have occasions
>   like the first two rows, which have the same `user_id` and `place_id`
>   and thus I get the results of `2018-06-24 06:52:51`-`2018-06-24 05:15:07` 
>   *and* `2018-06-24 06:52:51`-`2018-06-09 12:56:12`. I only need the first difference.
>
> Imagine time1 is an arrival and time2 is a departure. Basically my problem boils down to finding which trains or airplanes are running. I need some way to understand that `2018-06-24 06:52:51`-`2018-06-24 05:15:07` is the same and that 
>   `2018-06-24 06:52:51`-`2018-06-09 12:56:12` is not the same train/airplane.

Since I want to translate the code to `SQL` the solution must be based on `dplyr`. I tried something like `df1 %>% group_by(user_id,place_id)`, but I am definitely stuck now. Here is some sample data

```
set.seed(42)
u <- runif(1000, 0, 60) # "noise" to add or subtract from some timepoint
df1<-data.frame(time1=as.POSIXlt(sort(u)*100000, origin = "2018-05-03 08:00:00"),
                user_id=sample(rep(paste0('sdkID',1:60)),1000,replace=TRUE),
                place_id=sample(rep(paste0('place_ID',1:60)),1000,replace=TRUE))

df1=df1[order(df1$user_id,df1$place_id,df1$time1),]

df2=df1[-sample(1:1000,200),]  
df2$time1<-df2$time1+u[-sample(1:1000,200)]*100

## cleaning up
colnames(df2)[1]='time2'
rownames(df1)=1:1000
rownames(df2)=1:800
```

Comment: timestamp match means u wanna match exactly timestamp or date or month or on what parameter u wanna to be match 2 data frames? and what u r expecting to be the output contains?

Comment: What is the time criterion? A difference less than a certain threshold? If so, please edit the question with that information.

Comment: @5th,  sample data is good but 1000 rows is too much. Please reduce to a minimal meaningful  that relates to your desired result

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I updated my problem description (yellow box) @RuiBarradas yes, I edited that: `time2-time1>0`. @saisaran: I updated that part (yellow box) @AndrewLavers: I tried lowering the sample size to 100, but it only makes the issue less comprehensible. I think the problem description was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @RuiBarradas and @kon_u answers I managed to solve my problem. Since both only partly understood the problem (partly due to me not formulating the problem description clear enough), I share here my complete solution:

```
result<-df1 %>%
       left_join(df2, by = c("user_id", "place_id")) %>%
       mutate(Diff = difftime(time2, time1, units = "secs"),
                           Diff = as.numeric(Diff)) %>%
       filter(Diff > 0) %>%
       arrange(user_id, place_id, time1,time2) %>%
       group_by(user_id, place_id,time2) %>% 
       filter(Diff==min(Diff)) %>%
      right_join(df1,by=c("user_id", "place_id","time1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest using lubridate: working with dates and time in R to calculate the minimum time difference.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Codes Given
set.seed(42)
u <- runif(1000, 0, 60) # "noise" to add or subtract from some timepoint
df1<-data.frame(time1=as.POSIXlt(sort(u)*100000, origin = "2018-05-03 08:00:00"),
                user_id=sample(rep(paste0('sdkID',1:60)),1000,replace=TRUE),
                place_id=sample(rep(paste0('place_ID',1:60)),1000,replace=TRUE))

df1=df1[order(df1$user_id,df1$place_id,df1$time1),]

df2=df1[-sample(1:1000,200),]  
df2$time1<-df2$time1+u[-sample(1:1000,200)]*100

# dplyr operations
df_3 = df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('user_id', 'place_id'))
df_3$time_diff = abs(ymd_hms(df_3$time1.x) - ymd_hms(df_3$time1.y))
df_3 %>% 
    arrange(-desc(user_id), -desc(place_id), -desc(time_diff)) %>% 
    group_by(user_id, place_id) %>%
    slice(which.min(time_diff))
```

[image]

**Further Resources:**

1. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html
2. [Calculating Time Difference between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033585/calculating-time-difference-between-two-columns)
3. https://data.library.virginia.edu/working-with-dates-and-time-in-r-using-the-lubridate-package/

Comment: Thank your solution brought my question on the right track. I edited my question. I hope now the problem I face is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following solves your problem.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("user_id", "place_id")) %>%
  mutate(Diff = difftime(time1.y, time1.x, units = "secs"),
         Diff = as.numeric(Diff)) %>%
  filter(Diff > 0) %>%
  arrange(user_id, place_id, time1.x) %>%
  group_by(time1.x) %>%
  mutate(time1 = first(time1.x), time2 = time1.y) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Diff, -time1.x, -time1.y)

head(result)
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#  user_id place_id   time1               time2              
#  <fct>   <fct>      <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1 sdkID1  place_ID1  2018-05-14 06:53:01 2018-05-14 08:24:30
#2 sdkID1  place_ID18 2018-06-05 04:38:53 2018-06-05 06:12:35
#3 sdkID1  place_ID19 2018-05-22 19:20:40 2018-05-22 19:49:17
#4 sdkID1  place_ID25 2018-06-15 08:55:55 2018-06-15 10:18:58
#5 sdkID1  place_ID27 2018-05-06 17:34:40 2018-05-15 17:17:48
#6 sdkID1  place_ID27 2018-05-06 17:34:40 2018-06-11 15:14:07
```

Comment: Thanks that is further down the right track. But now to get exactly the result I need you need to add `arrange(user_id, place_id, time1,time2) %>%
       group_by(user_id, place_id,time2) %>% 
       filter(Diff==min(Diff)) %>%
      right_join(df1,by=c("user_id", "place_id","time1"))` after `filter(Diff>0)`. Then you get the same 1000 rows you started with.